# @babel/preset-env do i need to add core-js to support all modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, webpack, config, babeljs

Trying to look for an answer on Google. After installing `babel-preset-env` and using `"useBuiltIns"   : "usage"` do i still need the following rule by default: `"corejs"        : "3"`

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "useBuiltIns"   : "usage",
                "corejs"        : "3"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

This is my browserslistrc:

```
[development]
last 2 versions
last 1 Edge versions
last 2 Chrome versions
last 2 Firefox versions
last 2 Safari versions
last 2 Opera versions
not IE 11
not op_mini all
not dead
current node

[production]
last 2 versions
not IE 11
not op_mini all
not dead
maintained node versions
```

This topic always confuses me, I don't need support for IE11 since only support the last 2 versions of all browsers.

Is this browserslist support file stable and good? If not what would you suggest to add or remove?

Is it true that **USAGE** will automatically add core-js functions if needed?

Can someone explain me this for one and always.